# Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s) with entity framework

Tags: postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I have the following table:

[image]

And I have the following trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_insertion_to_pushes_table
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON "Pushes"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insert_failed_push();

CREATE or replace FUNCTION trg_insert_failed_push()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
BEGIN
    IF (NEW."Sent" = false) THEN
        IF EXISTS(
                SELECT *
                FROM "Pushes"
                where "Sent" = false
                  and "CustomerId" = NEW."CustomerId"
                  and "PushTemplateId" = NEW."PushTemplateId"
            )
        THEN
            RETURN NULL;
        END IF;
        RETURN NEW;
    ELSE
        RETURN NEW;
    end if;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

If there is row in the DB where `CustomerId` and `PushTemplateId` and `Sent` are equal to new row and `Sent` is false I would like to pass insertion.

And I have the following test to check how it works:

```
    public class Tests
    {
        private IPushRepository _pushRepository;
        [NUnit.Framework.SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {
            var confBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            var configuration = confBuilder.AddJsonFile("/home/aleksej/projects/makeapppushernet/TestProject/appsettings.LocalToProdDb.json").Build();
            _pushRepository = new PushRepository(new ApplicationDbContext(configuration));

        }

        [Test]
        public async Task Test1()
        {
            var push = new Push
            {
                CustomerId = 69164,
                Sent =  false,
                PackageId = "com.kek.lol",
                Category = "betting",
                Advertiser = "Advertiser",
                TemplateType = "opened_and_not_registration",
                IntervalType = "minutes",
                BottomDateTimeBorder =  90,
                TopDateTimeBorder = 60,
                ClientStartDateTime = DateTime.Now,
                FCMResponse = "hello",
                CreatedAt = DateTime.Now,
                LangCode = "En",
                PushBody = "Hello",
                PushTitle = "Hello",
                PushTemplateId = 15 
            };

            var pushesList = new List<Push>
            {
                push
            };

            await _pushRepository.SaveAsync(pushesList);

            Assert.Pass();
        }
    }
```

If I set `false` for `Sent` in the test I have  the following exception:

> Database operation expected to affect 1 row(s) but actually affected 0 row(s). Data may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=527962 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

If I  set `true` I have nothing. It just passes insertion.

### Update

Ok, with the help of Shay Rojansky's answer I have the following trigger code:

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_insertion_to_failed_pushes_table
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON "FailedPushes"
    FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE trg_insert_failed_push();

CREATE or replace FUNCTION trg_insert_failed_push()
    RETURNS trigger AS
$func$
DECLARE
    push        "FailedPushes"%ROWTYPE;
    old_push_id numeric;
BEGIN
    old_push_id = (SELECT "FailedPushId"
                   FROM "FailedPushes"
                   where "CustomerId" = NEW."CustomerId"
                     and "PushTemplateId" = NEW."PushTemplateId");
    push := new;

    IF (old_push_id != 0)
    THEN
        push."FailedPushId" = old_push_id;

        DELETE
        FROM "FailedPushes"
        where "CustomerId" = NEW."CustomerId"
          and "PushTemplateId" = NEW."PushTemplateId";

        return push;
    END IF;

    push."FailedPushId" = (SELECT count(*) FROM "FailedPushes")::numeric + 1;

    return push;
END
$func$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Maybe not very elegant but it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are in effect configuring PostgreSQL to ignore the INSERT under certain conditions, but EF Core isn't aware of this in any way. When you tell EF Core to add a new row, it expects for that to actually happen in the database. If the entity has any database-generated columns (identity, serial), EF Core also expects to receive the their values for the newly-inserted row (and will populate them back into the entity's CLR instance).

So AFAIK you can't just tell the database to ignore the INSERT and expect everything to work...

See [this issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/4526) on EF Core upsert support which is somewhat related.

Comment: You help me again and again, thank you! In the GitHub link that you had specified I found this library https://github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert. It looks like as solution.

Comment: But this library github.com/artiomchi/FlexLabs.Upsert can upsert only one row. I think the solution for my issue is select manually existing rows (according to parameters `CustomerId`, `PushTemplateId` and `Sent`) from DB, exclude these rows from the list for insertion, and insert. But I'm not sure about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your model parsing to Action in the controller might not have accurate values.